# Is $\inf_{y\in Y} \|\alpha x-y\|=\inf_{y' \in Y} \|\alpha x-\alpha y'\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In my functional analysis homework problem I was trying to a extend a linear functional from a proper sub-space $Y$ to the whole space $X \supset Y$using the Hahn Banach theorem. In order to do that I needed to find a positive homogenous and sub-linear functional $p$. If I chose it to be $p(x)=\inf_{y\in Y} \| x-y\|$
Now to show it is positive homogenous I need to show that
$p(\alpha x)=|\alpha|p(x)$ i.e
$\inf_{y\in Y} \|\alpha x-y\|=\inf_{y' \in Y} \|\alpha x-\alpha y'\|=|\alpha|\inf_{y\in Y} \| x-y'\|$

Now $\inf_{y\in Y} \|\alpha x-y\|=\inf_{y' \in Y} \|\alpha x-\alpha y'\|$ holds because we are computing the infimum over the whole subspace Y , in other words $\alpha y'$ is just a scalar multiple of $y$

My reasoning makes sense to me but I do not know how to exactly write it down mathematically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially said
$$
p(\alpha x) = \inf_{y \in Y} \|\alpha x - y \| = \inf_{y \in Y} \| \alpha x - \alpha y\| = |\alpha| \inf_{y \in Y} \| x-y\| = |\alpha|p(x), 
$$
you don't need to say more. Note that $y$ is a parameter so to speak, so you don't need to pick a new symbol $y'$, as long as equality is true you're fine. (In other words, you had it all right.)

Hope that helps,

Comment: To clarify the "trick" you might want to write
$$\ldots = \inf_{\alpha y \in Y} \|\alpha x - \alpha y\| = \ldots$$

Comment: Thank you for reading my proof. I was really helpful

Comment: @AlexR : I think OP already knew what the trick was, he just wanted to know how to write it down, which is what I did. =)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I know. The suggestion is more toward what the OP asked for: How to write it down. My suggestion _stresses_ the "trick" a bit ;)

Comment: @AlexR : So you were talking to the OP, not to me :P I thought you were talking to me!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I was talking to you as well. If you wrote that, the answer would be a little better (in my opinion).

Comment: @AlexR : I think that in mathematical writing it is good to know what the details look like if you write them all down (as the detail you explained for instance) but it shows weakness if you write down explicitly all details. So it is good to be able to write them to yourself on a sketch at home but when handing something in it is better to omit such things. That's why my answer is my answer.